# Async await в 3-х методах C#

Tags: c#, .net, async-await

Мне нужно запустить в консольном приложение 3 асинхронных 3 метода. Каждый метод создает бесконечный цикл в котором обрабатывает данные из источника по API и сохраняет асинхронно в базу. Метод должен работать пока я не выключу программу. Проблема в том что запускается только первый метод, до остальных двух не доходит. В качестве проверки вывожу надпись в консоле в каждом методе. Работает только первый. Все 3 метода одинаковы на 99% разница лишь в источнике и записи в свою таблицу. Вот код в кратце без внутренних действий. Лишь цепочка вызовов.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    FirstRobot first = new FirstRobot();
    SecondRobot second = new SecondRobot();
    ThirdRobot third = new ThirdRobot();

    first.StartFirst();
    second.StartSecond();
    third.StartThird();
}
```

Тут есть цепочка асинхронных методов. Во все 3х методах она одинакова. Первый метод сначала создает переменные и делает свои действия, потом внутри своего тела вызывает еще один асинхронный метод

```
public async Task StartFirst()
{
    await GetRobotResult(); // Тут стартует бесконечный цикл, и сюда прога возвращается после сохранения в базу.
}

async Task GetRobotResult()
{
    await robot.MyRobotTS()
}

public async Task MyRobotTS
{
    await addbaza.AddBazaMethod()
}

public async Task AddBazaMethod
{
    await db.SaveChangesAsync(); // Самый конец. Сохранение в базу.
}
```

Как заставить что работали сразу все 3 вечных метода?

Comment: `await GetRobotResult(); // Тут стартует бесконечный цикл и сюда` как именно стартует? Точно не синхронно?

Comment: Ну вообще да. Внутри самого метода уже не важно как они будут работать. Главное выделить 3 потока для каждого главного метода что запускаются в main

Comment: Если вам надо 3 потока, то юзайте `Task.Factory.StartNew(() => first.StartFirst(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);` для каждой из работ, или напрямую стартуйте треды.

Comment: Да, спасибо, все работает. Тогда последовательный вопрос. А нужно ли вообще тогда в цепочке все эти async await?

Comment: Нет, с тредами в вашем случае авайты и асунги не нужны. И вообще они далеко не везде полезны, но модны :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как пример, вы можете попробовать стартовать вашу, по всей видимости, синхронную работу (кода то вы так и не показали) следующим образом:

```
var tasks = new[]
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => first.StartFirst(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => first.StartFirst(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning),
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() => first.StartFirst(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning)
};

Task.WaitAll(tasks);
```

Тут мы стартуем 3 одинаковые работы, даем понять шедулеру, что работы долгоиграющие (он скорее всего выделит тред для каждой из работ), и после синхронно ждем когда всё это кончится.

Comment: Я обязательно попробую этот метод. Но в коментах выше успели дать ответ который решил задачу. Я так понимаю разница не особо большая кроме как показывать что задачи длинные. За ответ спасибо!

Comment: @FX_Sektor в комментах выше я вам и дал ответ :) Коротко говоря, если вам нужно запустить долгую задачу на процессоре в отдельном треде, то async-await для этого вещь не обязательная. Но если вы работаете с диском/сетью/чем то, что не занимает CPU или просто ожидаете время, то async-await может сэкономить вам ресурсы процессора

Comment: Пометил как правильный ответ. Спасибо! п.с. Я не внимательный:)

Comment: @FX_Sektor пожалуйста